# Adding Custom Python library in Azure Synapse

Tags: python, azure, azure-synapse

I have spinned up a notebook in Azure Synapse workbook and I have attached an Apache Spark pool and I am installing my python sdk in there by running command in first block of my notebook with code as `"from XYZ import XYZ.client"` but I get error as

> "Module "XYZ" not found error.

How do i fix this? I have the python wheel package of XYZ with me. can someone guide me the steps in Azure Synapse

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-manage-workspace-packages

Comment: I did this still i get the error.I added the wheel file in my Workspace package and then I run teh notebook by attaching the Apache Spark pool.. and I get the error. I tried running command like "pip install xyz" then it says syntax error. Not sure if there is anything with Apache spark pool configuration

Comment: After adding to workspace package, did you added that to apache spark pool package?

Comment: yes I did..also I am checking another workspace where I see in Apache spark pool there is User provisioned Spark Configuration file but there is a message saying "Uploading user-provisioned Apache Spark configuratios are no longer supported. Select an Apache Spark configuration from the dropdown list below. " I dont see any drop down. How do i do it in my new workspace. i am hoping that is the issue not able to provide the Spark configuration

Comment: I get error as "TypeError: bases must be types"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding your `.whl` file in to the workspace packages.

[image]

Again you need to add it to  spark pool package as below.

Go-To **Apache Spark pool**
click on **More** option in your spark pool, then **packages**.

[image]

You will get option to upload in different ways as below.
First, enable **Allow session level packages** option,
then under **Workspace packages** select the file you uploaded in workspace earlier and click on **apply** settings.

[image]

If you don't have any `.whl` files just create `requirements.txt` add required packages and upload here under **Requirements files**.
After clicking on apply settings wait for some time to successfully apply settings.
Then, go to notebook stop the current session and run notebook  in new spark session.

[image]

Make sure you run notebook in new session after adding packages.

Comment: I did this and I get error as "TypeError: bases must be types"

Comment: That is some dependency conflict within packages. Try earlier version of the package.If possible provide the package name so i could try in my environment.

Comment: yes this is the sdk "https://pypi.org/project/cognite-sdk/" and the command I get error is from " from cognite.client import CogniteClient "

Comment: you can't able to do `pip install cognite-sdk`? what is the error you getting? which is the python version you using?

Comment: i am able to do pip install cognite-sdk. No error there. Error is on this command " from cognite.client import CogniteClient

Comment: Try re installing protobuf  `pip install protobuf==3.16.0`.

Comment: okay works.Thanks!!